# Editing the Top.phtml

Tags: theme, template, menu, navigation

First off I just want to say thank you to who ever can help me, I'm currently using the MT Cosmetic Theme, but if I go to /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/navigation/top.phtml and edit that, nothing changes I've recached the site as well, can anyone help?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

The chances our the package/theme will have it's own version of this file. Try looking in the following places.

```
app/design/frontend/{MT Cosmetic}/default/template/catalog/navigation/top.phtml
```

But to find out exactly which templates are used you can turn on template hints via the admin section. Under System->Configuration you need to set current configuration scope to your Store and then then select Developer->Debug to find these settings.